# How to prevent cursor from getting stuck in winform control due to validation

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I'm trying to implement validation on a winform using the error provider and validation events but I'm finding it gives a rather unnatural flow to the form.  Upon opening the form, I set the focus to a text box but if a user was to select another control within the form, they get trapped in the text box until data is entered.  I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening, I really don't like the behavior where the cursor get stuck in any control until valid data is entered.

What I would like to do is have a flag show up beside the control with invalid data but allow the user the freedom to move to other controls on the form but not permit the form to be saved if it contains invalid data.  Is this possible with the error provider and validation events?  If not, what is the best way to accomplish the type of validation I've outlined?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do the validation in an async way?

Comment: As long as you set e.Cancel to *true* in the Validating event then you'll trap the user.  It is up to you to extend this, ErrorProvider just displays a warning icon, they didn't make it a "validate the entire form" kind of control.  What's in the toolbox are little Lego blocks, up to you to stack them together.